# Почему возникает проблема scrollBy в присутствии IntersectionObserver?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

Всем здравствуйте.
Задача следующая:

1. Иметь на странице IntersectionObserver для переключения активных пунктов меню.
2. Иметь на странице scrollBy для плавного скролла по якорям.
   Увидел такую проблему: scrollBy прокручивает до элемента неверно, немного путая координаты, нажимая второй раз на ту же кнопку - скролл верно встаёт на позицию.
   Когда удаляю код IntersectionObserver, то такой баг пропадает, scrollBy прокручивает сразу как положено.
   Код:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     const sections = document.querySelectorAll("[data-observer-section]");
     const navs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-observer-nav]");
     setActiveLink();
     window.addEventListener('hashchange', setActiveLink);

     // Прокрутка к элементу
     navs.forEach(nav => {
       nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();    
           const href = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);    
           const scrollTarget = document.querySelector("#" + href);    
           const elementPosition = scrollTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top;
           const offsetPosition = elementPosition - topOffset;    
           console.log(elementPosition)
           window.scrollBy({
               top: offsetPosition,
               behavior: 'smooth'
           }); 
       });
     });

   const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
       entries.forEach(entry => {            
           if(entry.isIntersecting ) {                
               location.hash = entry.target.getAttribute("id");
           }
       });    
     }, {  threshold: 0.55, rootMargin: sensitivity + "px" });       

   sections.forEach( section => {
       observer.observe(section);
   });

   function setActiveLink(){ 
       let hash = location.hash;
       console.log(hash)
       navs.forEach(nav => {
           if (nav.getAttribute("href") === hash) {
               nav.classList.add("active");
               nav.scrollIntoView({ inline: "center"});
           } else {
               nav.classList.remove("active");
           }
       });
   }});
   ```

Comment: Если я правильно помню, любое изменение location.hash автоматически прокручивает до указанного элемента и тем самым собьёт ваш scrollBy, возможно в этом дело

Comment: @andreymal Действительно, спасибо за подсказку. Упустил этот момент. (когда в обсервере убрал этот код, все ок). Но что можно предпринять в таком случае? Я уже пробовал добавлять дополнительные символы в хеш (чтобы они не совпадали с реальными, а при проверке удаляю). Но проблема не ушла.

Comment: Если вы хотите менять адресную строку, попробуйте history.pushState/replaceState

Comment: @andreymal
В общем, не в хеше дело, а в горизонтальном скролле панели с пунктами меню. Отключение этого функционала исправило ошибку. Теперь новый тупик.
Поясню: в шапке находится nav с пунктами меню (классы которых я и переключаю во время скролла), позиция у него sticky, присутствует горизонтальный скролл в блоке. Вот, при переключении, активный пункт меню должен оказываться на середине, т.е автоматически скроллиться.
Сразу пробовал с помощью scrollIntoView, потом функцию писал со scrollLeft - не помогает. Точнее, меню-то скроллится, а тело документа так и промахивается.

Comment: @andreymal Точнее, не только в хеше. Вот такое пояснение я получил на другом ресурсе:
"Когда вы используете window.scrollBy на это реагирует IntersectionObserver и изменяет hash в адресе страницы, на это реагирует событие hashchange которое вызывает функцию setActiveLink которая в свою очередь вызывает nav.scrollIntoView({ inline: "center"});. Следовательно nav.scrollIntoView создает эту проблему.
А при повторном нажатии IntersectionObserver не отрабатывает так как объект и так в зоне видимости."